# Linking React components using props.childern

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I'm trying to build a tab system with my basic react knowledge. To use the tab system you'd do something like this.

```
<Tabs onChange={this.handleTabChange}>
    <Tab id="home" title="Home">
    ...
</Tabs>
```

The Tabs component will render it's childern with {this.props.childern}

The Tab component needs to communicate to the outer Tabs component that it has been clicked and the outer component keeps track of "currentTab" in it's state.

If I were hard coding the Tabs and Tab components I could pass props from parent to child but as these components are going to be used repeatedly and are "dynamic" in the sense that they could comtain any childern I don't know where to begin wiring them up together.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: So, do you want to render n Tab components inside the Tabs component and when some Tab component receives a click, you want tell the Tabs component which Tab component got the clicked, right?

Comment: Yes, somebody pointed me in the direction of a similar question I hadn't found which appears to contain the answer. Thanks.